# How do i use componentWillReceiveProps() correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a child component as soon as it recieves new props. However, `componentWillReceiveProps()` in my child component is called before the props have actually updated. After reading [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html) i do understand why but it doesn't explain me how to solve my problem.

How do i call `componentWillReceiveProps()` **after** the props have updated?

Right now i'm cheating my way around it by letting a timeout run which waits for the actual update, but i really don't like this solution.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(){
   var timeOut = setTimeout(() => this.loadPosts(), 100)
  },
```

Thanks id advance!

Comment: just pass prop to child component  inside render.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it necessary to call `componentWillReceiveProps` *after* the props have updated? Or can you use the [`nextProps` argument](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)?

Eg. if you rewrite as:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  this.loadPosts(nextProps)
},
```

and then of course also rewrite the signature of `loadPosts` to allow manually passing in props:

```
loadPosts(props = this.props){
  // do something with props
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). When it's called, two arguments are passed: `prevProps` and `prevState`. This is the inverse of `componentWillUpdate`. The passed values are what the values were, and `this.props` and `this.state` are the current values.

Comment: but this is not called when the component recieves new props :/

Comment: It's called if the component is updated. If you need the new props but your component will not be updated or you are using `shouldComponentUpdate` you need to use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` where `nextProps` are the new props: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops